# How to use JWT with WebSocketChannel in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, jwt

I have an existing Websocket Channel which needs authenticate user by his JWT in order to send/receive messages using this socket connection. The problem is - I don't know how to send my access token in message body when establishing connection. The official documentation says:

"If the url contains user information this will be passed as basic authentication when setting up the connection."

But in my case JWT is passed in a message like this:

```
{"method":"auth","accessToken":"${MY_TOKEN}"}
```

I tried to connect by passing JWT in headers or use sink after connection is established, but when I send a new message, it only calls onDone callback and closes connection.

```dart
  final _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('${WEB_SOCKET_URL}');

...

  void initState() {
    _channel.stream.listen((message) {
      print('message');
    }, onError: (error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('error');
    }, onDone: () {
      print('done');
    });

    _channel.sink.add({
      "method": "auth",
      "accessToken": "${MY_TOKEN}"
    });
}
```

I expect connection to be established and then I can use it to send/received messages but it's only closes when I try to use "sink.add()" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send an object on the socket I think it is not happy with that. The server may not be able trop properly handle the error of receiving something other than a json string and closes the connection.

Try this to send a json string:

```
    var message = {
      "method": "auth",
      "accessToken": "${MY_TOKEN}"
    };

    _channel.sink.add(jsonEncode(message));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but nope, still the same error.

Comment: Do you enter `onError` or `onDone`?

Comment: It enters onDone again

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to this method. This is easy as mentioned in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/WebSocket/connect.html

```
  final WebSocketChannel channel =
  IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://<socketurl>/ws/",headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': 'Bearer $yourtoken'
  });
```

Comment: This throws a platform error with flutter web.

Comment: The headers don't work here. ```{"type":"connection_error","payload":{"message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Authorization')"}}```

Comment: is it still unsupported for Flutter Web?

Answer (score 3):

You may pass it in the URL:

```
WebSocketChannel.connect("ws://localhost:8080/api/foo/ws?authorization=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1...")
```

Using `IOWebSocketChannel` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68030147/8162252) throws a platform error if used with flutter web, whereas `WebSocketChannel` automatically determines the proper platform.

> Traditionally it was considered poor practice to have credentials in
> query params because URLs can get stored in places such as logs for
> proxies, browser history, etc. **However, neither of those concerns
> apply to websockets** (a browser won't keep history of the connections
> made by a page), and proxies do not have access to the URL when there
> is a TLS tunnel. This concern arose when non-TLS interactions were the
> default.

[source](https://support.ably.com/support/solutions/articles/3000075120-is-it-secure-to-send-the-access-token-as-part-of-the-websocket-url-query-params-)

Comment: So as of 2023 this is considered as the most secured way?